# AzureOffline Sync with Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

AZURE OFFLINE SYNC
•   Mobile App creation in AzurePortal.
•   Mapped App to existing DB.
•   Download webApp for Api in C# approach.
•   I am using Entity Framework DB First approach.
•   Created Azure Mobile App Table Controller.
•   Selected relevant ModleClass/DataContext & Controller Name.
•   Hosting of Api is completed.
•   Created one Shared Xamarin Project.
•   Add required sdk (Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client, Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore.)

•   Based on Microsoft Documentation I created one ServicePage ( communicate with the Cloud Back-end)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data

**Issue Which I am facing**
•   There is some code structure that is related to offline sync and online sync.
•   We need to enable OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED for fetching the data and store it sqlite.
•   I am able to fetch data in online mode (Without enabled Offline_sync)
•   Moment when I enabled OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED , not able to fetch data.
•   My code is debugging but after execution of PullAsync it is not able to fetch data.

I am Following Microsoft instruction only. Changes  I made , I am using DB_First Approach.
And creating model for Local storage, based on my project requirement.
I have explored multiple example, every example is available in code first approach only, not a single example I am getting in DB_First Approach.

if you have any solution for that plese send to me.